# Autonomous Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For the solution of the autonomous equation $$y'=y(1-y)(y+2)$$ find $\lim_{t\to\infty} y(t)$ provided $y(0)=-1$.

The answer is $-2$.

I am wondering how they got this answer.
Did they take the critical points and then take $y''$ to find the rest of the behavior?
I am not sure how they got to this answer.

Comment: Well actually in this concrete case you can compute exactly the solution, right? It should involve logarithms. Just use partial fraction expansion

Comment: @Moo in this case I would have to look at the inflection points?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=x(1-x)(2+x)$.

Solving $f(x)=0$ yields $x=0,1,-2$.

By unicity of solutions, $y(t)$ must non cross the solutions $y_2(t)=0$ and $y_3(t)=-2$. We have $y(0)=-1$, hence the solution is bounded so it is defined for all $t \geq 0$. Furthermore, $f(x)$ is stricly negative on $(-2,0)$. So $y$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,\infty[$.

Since $y$ is bounded below and strictly decreasing, it converges. If it converges, it converges to an equilibrium point. Hence the result.